# Gitlab links to "https://gitlab/"

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-omnibus

I installed gitlab in a docker container from the official image `gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest`. This image has all config in the file `gitlab.rb`. Https is done by a nginx reverse proxy.

My problem is, that when gitlab has an absolute link to itself, it links always to `https://gitlab/`. This host also can be seen in the "New group" dialog: [image: Group path starts with https://gitlab/]

#### Docker call:

```
docker run \
       --name git \
       --net mydockernet \
       --ip 172.18.0.2 \
       --hostname git.mydomain.com \
       --restart=always \
       -p 766:22 \
       -v /docker/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab \
       -v /docker/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab \
       -v /docker/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab \
       -d \
       gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

#### gitlab.rb:

```
external_url 'https://git.mydomain.com'
ci_nginx['enable'] = false
nginx['listen_port'] = 80
nginx['listen_https'] = false

gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 766
```

#### Nginx config:

```
upstream gitlab {
    server 172.18.0.2;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name git.mydomain.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/mydomain.com.chained.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/my.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://gitlab/;
                proxy_read_timeout 10;
    }
}
```

I tried to replace the wrong url wit nginx. This worked for the appearance like in the screen shot, but not for the links:

```
sub_filter 'https://gitlab/' 'https://$host/';
sub_filter_once off;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. It was in the nginx reverse proxy config. I named the upstream "gitlab" and somehow this name found it's way into the web pages:

```
upstream gitlab {
    server 172.18.0.2;
}
...
proxy_pass http://gitlab/;
```

I didn't expect that. I even omitted the upstream part in my original question because I thought the upstream name is just an internal name and will be replaced by the defined ip.

So the fix for me is, to write the full domain into the upstream:

```
upstream git.mydomain.com{
    server 172.18.0.2;
}
...
proxy_pass http://git.mydomain.com/;
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set your url correctly in your mapped volume `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb`

```
external_url 'https://git.mydomain.com'
```

Run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure` for the change to take effect.